# including shinyBS in a package

Tags: r, shiny, package, shinybs

When I build, load and run my own package, it is only using shinyBS functionalities if i beforehand load shinyBS with 'library(shinyBS)' otherwise tooltips are not working.. and although the shiny app works (whithout shinyBS features) there are webpage errors that can be seen through the browser console.. (about some missing files..shinyBS.css and shinyBS.js)

So the questions is: How can i generate, deploy and run my own shiny package without forcing the user to load shinyBS beforehand (doing 'library(shinyBS)' ) ?!

Thank you!

Comment: Your package should "import" the package, both by including it in `DESCRIPTION` as `Imports: shinyBS`, and including it in `NAMESPACE` with `import(shinyBS)` or `importFrom(shinyBS,functionname)` for each function you use. Then in your package code, you should use the double-colon notation, e.g., `shinyBS::bsModal` instead of just `bsModal`. Both the book and website are good references: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/

Comment: Alternative: use `Suggests: shinyBS` and include a condition of `if (require("shinyBS")) use_shinybs <- TRUE` at the start of each shiny app. From there, do `if (use_shinybs) shinyBS::bsModal(...)`, etc. Use this only if using it is *nice* but not *required*. (For this, do not include it in `NAMESPACE`.)

Answer (score 5):

The usual way of adding dependencies to an R package is to add the packages in the `Imports` Field of the `DESCRIPTION` file. Here is an adaped version from [Hadley Wickam's introduction](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html).

```
Package: mypackage
Title: What The Package Does (one line, title case required)
Version: 0.1
Authors@R: person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@example.com",
                  role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph)
Depends: R (>= 3.1.0), shiny
Imports: shinyBS
License: What license is it under?
LazyData: true
```

Then you will need to specify which functions from the `shinyBS` package are actually needed in the package with `importsFrom` in the `NAMESPACE` file. Alternatively, you can also import all `shinyBS` functions with

```
import(shinyBS)
```

---

However, in the case of `shinyBS`, you will actually need to put the dependency in the `Depends` field because of the way the `onLoad/onAttach` hooks are defined for that package. For more dertails, see [here](https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/issues/100). Your `DESCRIPTION` file should therefore look like the following example

```
Package: mypackage
Title: What The Package Does (one line, title case required)
Version: 0.1
Authors@R: person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@example.com",
                  role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph)
Depends: R (>= 3.1.0), shiny, shinyBS
License: What license is it under?
LazyData: true
```

This is quite unusual and in my opinion, this issue should be fixed from the `shinyBS` developers. However, in the mean time using the `Depends` field to make sure `shinyBS` is attached is a viable workaround for the issue you described.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NAMESPACE` to declare that you need `shinyBS` loaded in your package.

For example in your `NAMESPACE` file you should do:

```
import(shinyBS)
```

Furthermore, as noticed by @r2evans, you should add `shinyBS` in the `Imports` part of your `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Imports: shinyBS
```

For more information check the R package website from Hadley Wickam: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports.

Comment: You need it in `DESCRIPTION`, too; without it, and there is no assurance that the package will be installed when this package is installed. (And it's `shinyBS`, for the record :-)

Comment: Actually, `shinyBS` needs to be in the `Depends` field. Otherwise, certain JavaScript resources are not loaded properly. See [here](https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/issues/100)